# IBM WAS JMX connection with JConsole using SOAP protocol

Tags: soap, websphere, jmx, network-protocols

I have a need to connect with IBM WAS JMX using SOAP protocol specifically, locally as well as remotely. I am looking for ways to get JMX data of IBM WAS with SOAP protocol on jconsole.

Tried with URL like `service:jmx:soap://<host>:<port>/jndi/JMXConnector` but it did not. What configuration needs to be done on IBM WAS side so as to connect with JConsole using SOAP protocol?

Even referred IBM WAS docs but could not find anything relevant - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ragt_rconnector_customp.html

Here are the few references that I referred for connecting IBMWAS JMX with JConsole using SOAP Protocol:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cjmx_overview.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/container_admservice_tasks.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/uagt_rconnector.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ragt_rconnector_customp.html

After doing the necessary configuration on IBM WAS server side as recommended there and also listing down here :

Server side Conf. steps, from UI :

- Security -> Global Security -> RMI/IIOP security -> CSIV2 inbound communication -> Under Csiv2 transport layer
  Change transport from SSL-supported to SSL-required.
- Security -> Global Security -> RMI/IIOP security -> CSIV2 outbound communication -> Under Csiv2 transport layer
  Change transport from SSL-supported to SSL-required.
- Set Servers >> ServerTypes >> Application servers >> server1 >> Administration services >> Configuration : Set Remote Connector & Local Connector as SOAP Connector under General Properties
- Set Servers >> ServerTypes >> Application servers >> server1 >> Administration services >> JMX Connectors : Set SOAPConnector Enabled = Yes
- Set Servers >> ServerTypes >> Application servers > server1 > Ports > SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS : Set Host = * under General Settings
- Application servers > server1 > Ports > BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS : Set Host = * under General Settings
- Restart IBM server

Getting following error while trying to connect -

> REST Error [400]: Bad Request -- Invalid parameter found in connection URL. Verify the provided connection configurations.

Comment: This is not much better than [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915414/connecting-ibm-was-using-soap-protocol) (and you should be trying to repair old questions rather than creating duplicates, as closed questions can count towards an automatic question ban).

Comment: Have you got network connectivity to the web server at `<host>:<port>`? If so, try curl or something to see if it is alive. Update your question with your findings please.

Comment: When you say you "Tried with URL", did you use code to do this? Or maybe Postman?

Comment: Tried by posting the url on JConsole and other application. It gave configuration error. Will try with curl command and update the question with findings.. Thanks

Comment: "It gave configuration error." - paste that, in full, into your question please. A block formatting tool is available. Do the curl stuff in addition, of course.

Comment: have added few more details regarding the analysis done so far